# Java Package netscape.javascript.JSObject in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a project demo from XTRD publick repository called renko-scalper but when i cloned and started the build command in ide it shows me the following error

[Output after executing build command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0Z1W.png)

Comment: Are you referring to this [JSObject](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.jsobject/netscape/javascript/JSObject.html) ?

Comment: yes the project uses the js object for web view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure to add `JDK_HOME\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar` file to the classpath in `File | Project Structure | SDKs` dialog:

[image]